# Leer varios datos en una URL - JSON con Node.js

Tags: nodejs, json, axios, get

Necesito poder leer varios datos desde una URL.

Se trata de un Json con varios productos. Si leo uno solo, me lo saca sin problema.

La cosa es cuando traigo todos los productos, no encuentro manera de que me funcione.

MÉTODO FUNCIONANDO PARA UN ARTICULO.

```javascript
async function getProducto(producto) {
    return await makeRequest(urlProductos +'buscar/'+ producto);
}
    
async function makeRequest(url) {
    return await axios.get(url);
}
    
const pro = await getProducto('monitor');
    
text: (pro.data.name)
```

METODO SIN FUNCIONAR PARA TRAER VARIOS ARTICULOS

```javascript
async function getAll() {
   return await makeRequest(urlProductos +'all/');  
}
   
async function makeRequest(url) {
  return await axios.get(url);
}
    
const todospro = await getAll();
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el JSON que se obtiene? Sin esa información no podremos ayudarte.

Comment: qué significa que no funciona? No trae nada? trae algo pero no sabes procesarlo? Se apaga el PC?